# Error eclipse: java was started but returned exit code=1

Tags: java, eclipse

Hace poco me instale la ultima versión del jdk, pero al iniciar Eclipse me salio este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que tiene que ver con el jdk, si el problema realmente es ese,alguien puede pasar link de la pagina oficial para descargar la ultima versión del jdk, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes instalado el último JDK, el problema es configurar Eclipse para que lo use correctamente. Si te fijas, pone que está intentando usar el ejecutable en `c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe`. Comprueba el path donde tienes el JDK instalado y usa sus ejecutables. Reinstalando eclipse (el instalador debería ser capaz de detectar el JDK) o [editando el fichero `eclipse.ini`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) deberías poder solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta Pablo Lozano. El problema en mi caso era que la version de Eclipse que estoy usuando es de x64 y mi version de Java 8 es de X86. Lo puedes verificar con este comando en cmd:

java -d64 -version

Y la solución fue instalar una version de java de x64 y cambiar la variable de entorno "Path" eliminando la de x86 y dejando solo la version de x64.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/333974)

Answer (score 0):

Tuve este error en Spring Tool Suite 4 después de usarlo más de 1 año. De pronto comenzó a fallar.

Primero verifique con el comando de una de las respuestas de arriba:

```
 java -d64 -version
```

Y efectivamente mi versión de java no era de 64 bits, este comando arrojo los siguientes resultados:

C:\ALGO\ALGO java -d64 -version
Error: This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.

Después descargue e instale la versión correcta del JDK en mi maquina y modifique mi archivo SpringToolSuite4.ini para que apunte a el archivo jvm.dll correcto.
Agregue esto ->C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin\server\jvm.dll
Una línea abajo del comando -vm y quite la línea anterior.

Este es un ejemplo de como quedo la parte del archivo que modifique

-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs

así estaba antes:

-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs